# Java error when running Minecraft: "...the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Tags: java, minecraft, oracle

**G**ood evening, morning or day to you, fellow Ubuntu users!

I have encountered a problem when trying to run Minecraft on Ubuntu MATE 18.04. I followed the instruction given on the website *How to Geek* [How to Install Minecraft on Ubuntu or Any Other Linux Distribution](https://www.howtogeek.com/198476/how-to-install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux-distribution/), adding the repository for Oracle Java 8 etc. After downloading `Minecraft.jar` from www.minecraft.net I executed the file (`java -jar Minecraft.jar`), but...it didn't go exactly as expected. The output I got was:

> Downloading:
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
>   Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:
>   the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
>
> Downloading:
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
>   (try 2/10)

...and so on.

Do you perhaps know how to solve this problem?

This information, displayed while launching Minecraft, may be of use:

> System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
>   System.getProperty('os.version') == '4.15.0-20-generic'
>   System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
>   System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_171'
>   System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
>   System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'

Any advice on this topic will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

/Robert.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/991636/787506) will work for you? There are other suggestions in this question as well.

Comment: Have a look at this question over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty. It may be of help. I would try the suggestion to issue the command `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure` to setup your certificate trust store.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same exact problem.  What I did to fix it was:

```
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Go to the [**Java website**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html) and download the .tar.gz linux file.
 Extract the file from the archive:

```
jdk-10.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz/jdk-10.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar/jdk-10.0.1/lib/security/cacerts
```

Copy the file to

```
/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I didn't want to have to use snapcraft (personal technical preference more than anything), so I'm glad this worked!

Answer (score 2):

Just install Minecraft from Snap store-

```
sudo snap install mc-installer
```

Start the app after installation.

Comment: This was very quick and easy. Normally no need to reboot though.